# Use single Google OAuth client across GAS library consumers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

Every new copy of my Google Apps Script counts as a different client to Google Cloud, even though my code is in a library they each are sharing. I'd therefore like to specify my own oauth client created within the Google Cloud project, using its consent screen similar to before.

I know how to create said client, but I don't know how to get the consumers of my library (the scripts that call it and their containers) to all use the same client.

How would I accomplish this?

Edit:

Scenario: Script A is a library that needs to oauth authenticate. Script B is a consumer of that library attached to a spreadsheet C. Copies of that Spreadsheet C are counting as new clients. I would like them to use the same oauth client id.

Comment: Have you tried sharing the library (at least view-level access) with all potential users of the library and then giving them the script ID? If this does not work, can you share with us how you gave `Every new copy of my Google Apps Script` to your consumers?

Comment: Script A is a library. Script B is a consumer of that library attached to a spreadsheet C. Copies of that Spreadsheet C count as new clients.

Comment: Also, I can not share the library as it contains script properties that I do not want to expose.

Comment: I see. As far as I know, when another user makes a copy of a file (a spreadsheet as an example), the bound script will still be copied over to the new file. Unfortunately, I believe that the expected behavior for this scenario is that it will be counted as a new file (owned by another user) with a new client id.

Comment: @PatrickdC hmm... I can create a oauth client in Google cloud. Is there anyway to use that client instead?